# How do I write functions that accept unlimited arguments?

Tags: c++, function, variables, parameters, arguments

I have only been able to find **one** way for functions to take a variable amount of arguments.
It's this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

using namespace std;

void Print(int argumentAmount, ... );

int main()
{
    Print(5,11,22,33,44,55);
}

void Print(int argumentAmount, ... ){

    va_list arguments; 
    va_start(arguments, argumentAmount);

    int parameter;
    for(int i = 0; i < argumentAmount; ++i ){
        parameter = va_arg(arguments, int);
        cout << parameter << endl;
    }

    va_end(arguments);
    return;
}
```

**2 Problems:**
**1.)** I have to specify how many arguments I'm sending in- not desirable
**2.)** I can't figure out how to modify it so it will output strings.

Would something like this be possible without having to overload the function multiple times:

```
void Output(/*not sure how this would look*/);

int main(){

    Output("hello","world");
    Output("this","is","a","test");
    Output("As","many","strings","as","you","want","may","be","passed","in");

    return 0;
}
void Output(/*not sure how this would look*/){

    //loop through each string passed in and output it
}
```

What about this:

```
void Capitalize(/*all passed by reference*/);

int main(){

    string s1 = "hello";
    string s2 = "world";

    string s3 = "this";
    string s4 = "is";
    string s5 = "a";
    string s6 = "test";

    string s7 = "as";
    string s8 = "many";
    string s9 = "strings";
    string s10 = "as";
    string s11 = "you";
    string s12 = "want";

    Capitalize(s1,s2);
    Capitalize(s3,s4,s5,s6);
    Capitalize(s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12);

    return 0;
}
void Capitalize(/*all passed by reference*/){

    //capitalize each string passed in

}
```

All I can think to do is:
-overload the function multiple times
-have the function accept some type of container instead

If this is **NOT POSSIBLE**, could someone explain why the compiler is not capable of accomplishing a task like this.

Comment: Uh, the solution you provided at the top is the answer to the two questions raised at the bottom. What does it mean "modify it so it will output strings"?

Comment: So, why don't you just pass the strings around in an array or a collection of some sort?

Comment: Been a while since I looked at C - but a quick google found this: [http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2004/07/03/172616.aspx] which illustrates the syntax pretty well.

Comment: The compiler's only job is to compile C++ code.  Are you asking why the C++ language doesn't have support for that syntax?

Comment: By the way, "unlimited arguments" is a bit steep; I just found out today that C compilers are not required to support more than 127 parameters!

Comment: Another way is to have a terminating argument like 0 or NULL, which is isn't too much different than what you already have.

Comment: You can use variadic templates for this

Answer (score 63, accepted):

With variadic templates in C++11, you can do something like this (see [the result at ideone](http://ideone.com/jxZRS))

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void Output() {
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

template<typename First, typename ... Strings>
void Output(First arg, const Strings&... rest) {
    std::cout<<arg<<" ";
    Output(rest...);
}

int main() {
    Output("I","am","a","sentence");
    Output("Let's","try",1,"or",2,"digits");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I think you just helped me understand variadic templates.

Comment: Wait, won't the second call in main actually create 5 different function in memory, or is it actually recursive?

Comment: Yes, each call to Output<> has a different set of template arguments, and so results in a different template instantiation. Whether the compiler will actually create all these instantiations "in memory" or inline into the caller depends on the function code, optimization level etc.

Comment: Very good example

Answer (score 19):

Quick and simple answer.

For C++ you need to specify either the number of arguments or a sentinel value to indicate the end of arguments.

Your first example is a good example of specing the count, you could also do:

```
void Print(const char *arg, ... ){
    va_list arguments;

    for (va_start(arguments, arg); arg != NULL; arg = va_arg(arguments, const char *)) {
        cout << arg << endl;
    }

    va_end(arguments);
}
```

Where your calling convention is:

```
Print("foo","bar",NULL);
```

If you want to take it to the next level, you can mix in a bit of the C Preprocessor and do:

```
#define mPrint(...) Print(__VA_ARGS__, NULL)
```

Now you can just say:

```
mPrint("fooo","bar");
```

And the macro will `NULL` terminate the call.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of passing in the count, you can have a special "trailing" argument (either `nullptr` or a pointer to some hard-coded "magic" string) and your variable-argument functions should stop extracting more arguments once they see the trailing one. That can ease your coding a bit.

You could also pass pointers (references) to containers, containing (or pointing at/referencing) your strings. Anything that can somehow link all your individual arguments will do (e.g. a vector).

Example (might be not very idiomatic, but should serve as an illustration):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void AntiCapitalize(vector<string*>& v);
void Capitalize(string* s, ...);
void Print(string* s, ...);

int main()
{
    string s1 = "hello";
    string s2 = "world";

    string s3 = "this";
    string s4 = "is";
    string s5 = "a";
    string s6 = "test";

    string s7 = "as";
    string s8 = "many";
    string s9 = "strings";
    string s10 = "as";
    string s11 = "you";
    string s12 = "want";

    Capitalize(&s1, &s2, 0);
    Capitalize(&s3, &s4, &s5, &s6, 0);
    Capitalize(&s7, &s8, &s9, &s10, &s11, &s12, 0);

    Print(&s1, &s2, 0);
    Print(&s3, &s4, &s5, &s6, 0);
    Print(&s7, &s8, &s9, &s10, &s11, &s12, 0);

    vector<string*> v;
    v.push_back(&s1);
    v.push_back(&s2);
    v.push_back(&s3);
    v.push_back(&s4);
    v.push_back(&s5);
    v.push_back(&s6);
    v.push_back(&s7);
    v.push_back(&s8);
    v.push_back(&s9);
    v.push_back(&s10);
    v.push_back(&s11);
    v.push_back(&s12);

    AntiCapitalize(v);

    Print(&s1, &s2, 0);
    Print(&s3, &s4, &s5, &s6, 0);
    Print(&s7, &s8, &s9, &s10, &s11, &s12, 0);

    return 0;
}

void Capitalize(string* s, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, s);

    while (s)
    {
        string::size_type i = 0;

        while ((*s)[i] != '\0')
        {
            (*s)[i] = toupper((*s)[i]);
            i++;
        }

        s = va_arg(ap, string*);
    }

    va_end(ap);
}

void Print(string* s, ...)
{
    va_list ap;

    va_start(ap, s);

    while (s)
    {
        cout << *s << endl;
        s = va_arg(ap, string*);
    }

    va_end(ap);
}

void AntiCapitalize(vector<string*>& v)
{
    vector<string*>::iterator it;

    for (it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
    {
        string::size_type i = 0;

        while ((**it)[i] != '\0')
        {
            (**it)[i] = tolower((**it)[i]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
HELLO
WORLD
THIS
IS
A
TEST
AS
MANY
STRINGS
AS
YOU
WANT
hello
world
this
is
a
test
as
many
strings
as
you
want
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is another possible solution:
You could overload an operator '<<' like this:

```
class OutputObject {
public:
    // Some class functions/members

};
template<class T>
static operator << (OutputObject& out, T temp) {
    cout << temp;
}
static OutputObject Obj = OutputObject();
```

And then you can do the following in the main:

```
#include "OutputObject.hpp"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    string str = "Hello World";
    Obj << 12 << str << 3.14f << "C++";
    Obj << 12;
    Obj << str;
    return(0);
};
```

If I did something wrong or there is a reason not to that please
tell me, that was just my Idea of infinite parameters.
I was not able to test it yet, but I think it should work.

Comment: For future reference, you should hold off on posting until you've tested and verified your claims.

Comment: Sorry for that, my bad. Actually i tested it and it worked with one exception:
You cannot pass multiple classes in one call, but in multiples:
Obj << 12 << str ; is wrong because 12 is an integer and str a string, but 
Obj << 12; Obj << Str; works fine.
I just forgot to edit my post.

Comment: It should work, but it's hard to tell what you've done wrong because your code snippet is syntactically incorrect; you missed the return type. Presumably you gave it `void`. Don't do that